# How to mock Amazon S3 in an integration test

Tags: java, junit, amazon-s3, integration-testing

I'm trying to get an "walking skeleton" of my app up that will use S3 for persistence. I would like to use a fake S3 service so each developer's desktop can read/write at will.

I thought [mocks3](http://code.google.com/p/mocks3/) would be perfect, as I could get a jetty server up in my jUnit tests. The problem is that mocks3 doesn't allow any *writes*. Not even to set it up as far as I can tell.

So how do others do this?

Comment: If someone has the answer in other languages such as Ruby, please comment it!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is also an Findify [s3mock](https://github.com/findify/s3mock) tool written exactly for this purpose. It mocks the essential parts of AWS S3 API on top of local filesystem:

```
import io.findify.s3mock.S3Mock

S3Mock api = S3Mock.create(8001, "/tmp/s3");
api.start();

AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
// use local API mock, not the AWS one
client.setEndpoint("http://127.0.0.1:8001");
client.createBucket("testbucket");
client.putObject("testbucket", "file/name", "contents");
```

It's also easily embeddable and configuration-less.

Comment: One catch, If you are using kms encryption, basically
`putObjectRequest.setSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams());`
aws sdk will throw error saying https is required for using SSE, hence there has to be an if else in the code

Comment: @bestwishes any idea if there's a way to work around this without having an if else in code/if they've updated it since then?

Comment: @Steve I think I had an if else, but later on we moved to bucket level encryption(I don't know the exact name) in which we did not have to manually set SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(). But we could not get around this limitation.

Answer (score 16):

If you're ok with depending on a running docker container, and want something well-supported, you could consider using [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

Before running your tests, start S3 like so:

```
docker run --name localstack -d -p 5000:5000 -e SERVICES=s3:5000 localstack/localstack
```

And then stop it when tests complete like so:

```
docker stop localstack
```

You'll need to configure your S3 client to point to localhost:5000 for tests.  In Java, this can be done like so:

```
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                 "http://localhost:5000", 
                 "us-west-2"))
            .build();
```

Comment: seems like a docker solution would update along with the aws api's. nice

Answer (score 10):

Another option is [S3 ninja](http://s3ninja.net/) - emulates the S3 API for development and testing purposes.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [Adobe's S3Mock](https://github.com/adobe/S3Mock).  This S3 Mock server can be started via a Docker container or JUnit 4/5 rules.

Comment: This is a better option because s3mock is now public archive and has vulnerabilities in it.

Answer (score 7):

Tornado, a python web framework, has an example app that is just what you're looking for.

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/s3server/s3server.py

It can be used out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scality s3server, in can run on your machine either using node.js or via docker and it gives you a local S3 service instance. It's open source under a BSD license
[github.com/scality/s3](http://github.com/scality/s3)

Answer (score 0):

[LocalS3](https://github.com/Robothy/local-s3) is a good choice.

- It's based on Netty and without heavy other dependencies. Startup a LocalS3 service or [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/luofuxiang/local-s3) is super quick.
- Support commonly used AmazonS3 APIs. Include versioned objects, multipart uploads, etc.
- Support in-memory and persistence mode.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to scrap the jetty server and use [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) and the [S3 plugin](http://code.google.com/p/vfs-s3/). With that, you can use the memory or file-based storage implementations for the integration testing.

Comment: I believe this plugin acts as a client, not a server, making it impossible to achieve this use case with it.