# How to Mock "S3ClientConfiguration" for unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

have been trying for two days and not finding a solution to mock **S3ClientConfiguration** for unit test and pass it in **S3TransferManager.builder().s3ClientConfiguration(s3ClientConfiguration).build();**

is there a way to mock **S3ClientConfiguration** or **S3TransferManager** and use it for unit test java?

am using aws-sdk for java 2.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock Amazon S3 in an integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615988/how-to-mock-amazon-s3-in-an-integration-test)

Comment: no am looking for S3ClientConfiguration mocking which is part of aws-sdk java v2